# Ordering in ReaderWriterLock

Tags: c#, locking, readerwriterlock

When I use lock(){...}, I cannot garantee which thread will enter the lock first.

What about ReaderWriterLock? Does it works like a FIFO for the writers or not?

Answer (score 3):

> What about [ReaderWriterLock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlock.aspx)? Does it works like a FIFO for the writers or not?

It does.

And you pay a performance penalty for this, which is why [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim.aspx) was introduced—less overhead but it isn't "fair".

Comment: So ReaderWriterLock does the FIFO, but ReaderWriterLockSlim does not!?

Comment: Correct. the `RaaderWriterLock` documentation covers the details (when a writer leaves all pending readers get in, when they have all completed then the longest waiting writer gets in, ...).